# Is it possible to loop in conky

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, conky

Is there a way to loop in `conky`? For example, I have my `.conky` script that displays cpu load, however, it has to be reconfigured when I move to another machine. A trivial script like

```
sudo grep "processor" /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

gives information about the core count and *maybe* used in a loop like

```
${cpu cpu{1}}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not a conky/lua expert, so there may be a better way, but this works.
You need to create a lua script in, say, file `~/mylua.lua` containing

```lua
    local file = io.popen("grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo")
    local numcpus = file:read("*n")
    file:close()
    listcpus = ""
    for i = 1,numcpus
    do  listcpus = listcpus.."${cpu cpu"..tostring(i).."} "
    end

    function conky_mycpus()
     return listcpus
    end
```

and then in your `~/.conkyrc` you can add in the `conky.config={` part the line

```
lua_load = '~/mylua.lua',
```

(or for old conky versions pre 1.10 `lua_load ~/mylua.lua`)
and at the place where you want to have the cpu values, the line

```
${lua_parse conky_mycpus}
```

When conky starts the lua script will be run and the variable `listcpus` will end up being an appropriate string like `"${cpu cpu1} ${cpu cpu2}"`, depending on the number of processors found by grep.

Comment: any idea why this is occurring `execution failed: attempt to call a nil value`?

Comment: I tried this on  a fedora 22 and debian jessie with conky version 1.9 without any errors. You might try looking for debug info with `conky -DD`.

Comment: No additional debug info provided when using `-DD`.  conky version is 1.10, running arch + 4.7.5.1 kernel

Comment: 1.10 seems to have been a major change with some incompatibilities. Check [here](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Convert-to-new-1.10-syntax)  for some suggestions. It says the lua api has not changed, but the `.conkyrc` file has.

Comment: Yes, but it is smart enough to fallback to old syntax (at least in my case).

Comment: There is a handy script for conversion, though. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: I downloaded the latest 1.10.4_pre conky sources and recompiled them on my fedora 22 and it ran ok on the old `~/.conkyrc` file (after auto conversion). (The lua seems to be 5.3.3). So I don't know what is causing your problem. As usual the only thing to do is create simpler and simpler versions of both files until something works.  You can easily add simple debug like `print("here")` or `print(numcpus)` in the lua code and the output should appear on stdout.

Comment: this is currently not working.

Comment: @nyxee It still works for me. For such an old post and answer you should probably post a new question saying what you tried and what the result was.

Answer (score 4):

Do not forget to add a new line, otherwise it leads to unwanted results in the latest conky.

It's also important to load several luas in one line.

Example:

~/.conky/lua/cpu.lua

```
function conky_mycpus()
        local file = io.popen("grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo")
        local numcpus = file:read("*n")
        file:close()
        listcpus = ""
        for i = 1,numcpus
         do listcpus = listcpus.."${offset 15}Core "..tostring(i).." ${color ff8300}${cpubar cpu"..tostring(i).." 6}${color FFFDE2}\n"
        end

        return listcpus
end
```

loaded with

```
lua_load             = "/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/corky.lua ~/.conky/lua/cpu.lua",
```

If you dont load all your lua files in a single lua_load, it may throw "NIL Exceptions".

Comment: This has failed to work for me, even after extensive study. How do i get it to work as a starting point please.

Comment: depends what you mean with "failed". Log? Stacktrace?